# Issue getting the selected slot date in Kendo Scheduler

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I've got a Kendo Scheduler and I want something simple: to select a day and to get that selection information.

Here's the Scheduler:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<MyProj.Models.ScheduleInspectionModel>()
    .Name("scheduler")
    .Views(views =>
    {
        views.MonthView(mv => mv.Selected(true));
        views.AgendaView();
    })
    .Events(e => e.Change("test"))     <------------------------
    .Timezone("Etc/UTC")
    .Selectable(true)
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Read("GetScheduleInspections", "ControllerName")
    )
)
```

the Javascript function that is fired when a day is selected:

```
function test(e) {
    alert("hey");
}
```

The function is called and the alert is shown. I want to be able to do something like `e.date` to access the current date, for example. There is no intellisense and I can't find any API documentation to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the date in change function of scheduler use :

```
var date = e.start;
```

Yes, you are correct that intellisense is not available for this. So use can use client side debugging(for example using developers tool) to get all the available data.

Comment: OK, thank you, it works. I got what I wanted via `var selectedDate = kendo.format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", e.start);`